# Filling missing values with increasing values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe, which contains tool *id* and *time*.

For the last date I have tool *counter* values, and I need to fill up missing *counter* values in the dataframe by substracting *1* from the *counter* for each time the *id* has been used at a particular *date*.

```
data = {"id":["01","02","03","04","05",
          "02","02","03","05","04",
          "03","05","01","05","04",], 
    "counter": [100,200,300,400,500,
                np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,
                np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
   "date": ["2020-02-04","2020-02-04","2020-02-04","2020-02-04","2020-02-04",
            "2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02","2020-02-02",
           "2020-02-03","2020-02-03","2020-02-03","2020-02-03","2020-02-03"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_sort = df.sort_values(by=["id","date"], ascending = False)
```

Dataframe looks like this:

```
    id  counter date
4   05  500.0   2020-02-04
11  05  NaN     2020-02-03
13  05  NaN     2020-02-03
8   05  NaN     2020-02-02
3   04  400.0   2020-02-04
14  04  NaN     2020-02-03
9   04  NaN     2020-02-02
2   03  300.0   2020-02-04
10  03  NaN     2020-02-03
7   03  NaN     2020-02-02
1   02  200.0   2020-02-04
5   02  NaN     2020-02-02
6   02  NaN     2020-02-02
0   01  100.0   2020-02-04
12  01  NaN     2020-02-03
```

Desired outcome would be like this:

```
    id  counter date
4   05  500.0   2020-02-04
11  05  501     2020-02-03
13  05  502     2020-02-03
8   05  503     2020-02-02
3   04  400.0   2020-02-04
14  04  401     2020-02-03
9   04  402     2020-02-02
2   03  300.0   2020-02-04
10  03  301     2020-02-03
7   03  302     2020-02-02
1   02  200.0   2020-02-04
5   02  201     2020-02-02
6   02  202     2020-02-02
0   01  100.0   2020-02-04
12  01  101     2020-02-03
```

Please help me how can I do this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `groupby` the dataframe `df_sort` on `id` then forward fill the `counter` values per group using [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) and add them with a sequential counter created using [`groupby.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
g = df_sort.groupby('id')
df_sort['counter'] = g['counter'].ffill() + g.cumcount()
```

---

```
print(df_sort)

    id  counter        date
4   05    500.0  2020-02-04
11  05    501.0  2020-02-03
13  05    502.0  2020-02-03
8   05    503.0  2020-02-02
3   04    400.0  2020-02-04
14  04    401.0  2020-02-03
9   04    402.0  2020-02-02
2   03    300.0  2020-02-04
10  03    301.0  2020-02-03
7   03    302.0  2020-02-02
1   02    200.0  2020-02-04
5   02    201.0  2020-02-02
6   02    202.0  2020-02-02
0   01    100.0  2020-02-04
12  01    101.0  2020-02-03
```